# When I use a function as a script trigger, the script returns error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

as in the title.
I have a script that returns the built-in google sheets filter criterion. I tried to make a trigger so that the script executes every time I change the filter criteria.
It looks like this:
`=myscript(A1)` - In cell **A1**, I have a `=SUBTOTAL()` function as a trigger that returns a different number to the cell each time I change the filter criteria.
Unfortunately, `=myscript(A1)` returns `#Error! (without any description)` after changing the value in cell **A1**. But when I change the value of cell **A1** manually everything works and `myscript()` is executed.
What do you think about it?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using as well? What kind of trigger do you have? @AdOne

Comment: @ale13 I found a different solution. Instead of code, I used a function. VLOOKUP(SUBTOTAL(104,A:A),A:C,3,false) 
In column A, I added unique numbers for each row, and there is a filter in column C. It works for one criterion

Answer (score 1):

This is taken directly from the documentation on simple triggers:

`onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.`

Comment: Thanks,  this trigger unfortunately doesn't run when the filter criteria changes, but already found another solution.

Comment: There is no trigger that fires when data changes on the spreadsheet due to script or formula actions.